# Class not found error while loading data into Java RDD of custom class in Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I am pretty new to the Spark world and need help with this trivial problem.

I have a local spark running with one master and one slave, on the same machine.

I am using `Spring Boot` with `Gradle` to create my Java application that submits jobs to the Spark instance.

I have a service class which gets the `JavaSparkContext`:

```
public void loadTransactions(JavaSparkContext context) {
    try {
        List<TransactionRecord> transactionRecordList = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterable<TransactionRecord> all = trxRecordRepository.findAll();
        all.forEach(trx -> transactionRecordList.add(trx));
        System.out.println("Trx array list ready: "+ transactionRecordList.size());
        JavaRDD<TransactionRecord> trxRecordRDD = context.parallelize(transactionRecordList, 4);
        System.out.println(trxRecordRDD.count());
        System.out.println("data frame loaded");
    }catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error while loading transactions", e.getCause());
    }finally {
        context.close();
    }
}
```

When I execute this method, The `transactionRecordRepository` from spring data jpa, successfully populates the List.
The Spark job starts executing, but then fails with the following error:

```
2017-03-08 10:28:44.888  WARN 9021 --- [result-getter-2] o.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  : Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, 10.20.12.216, executor 0): java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: learning.spark.models.TransactionRecord
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1276)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition.readObject(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2122)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:258)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: learning.spark.models.TransactionRecord
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1819)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1986)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1919)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1529)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:552)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1269)
    ... 20 more
```

Everything works fine if I load a simpler data from a text file.

```
JavaRDD<String> movieData = context.textFile("/Users/panshul/Development/sparkDataDump/ratings.csv", 4);
            count = movieData.count();
```

My gradle build file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'spark-example'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.5")
    compile("org.codehaus.janino:janino:3.0.6")
    compile("org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.1.0")
            {
                exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-log4j12"
            }
    compile("org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.1.0")
            {
                exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-log4j12"
            }
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

Please help me figure out what am I doing wrong here.

Using `Spark version 2.1.0`
downloaded and installed from Spark website.
Running on MacOs Sierra.

Comment: could you, please, share your `build.gradle` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a jar of all the custom classes that I was using and put them in the `jars` folder of my Apache-Spark installation.

This made spark master discover the my custom RDD type classes and were propagated to the workers.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that your class *learning.spark.models.TransactionRecord* is not included in class-path when you submit the job.

You have to specify all depending jars in spark-submit --jars parameter or you have to create one big jar with all dependencies.

I think the easiest way is just submit multiple jars like this:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit  --name yourApp  --class yourMain.class  --master yourMaster --jars dependencyA.jar, dependencyB.jar, job.jar
```

Comment: also sharing your Gradle built would help

Comment: I am not submitting the jobs as a jar manually to Spark. I have a webservice running, which simply creates a SparkInstance and call the methods, which automatically submits the job to the Spark instance.

Comment: OK, but  still  cause of your problem will be the same, I guess learning.spark.models.TransactionRecord class ls missing from dependencies (I suppose, it is in separate project, that your main Spark job app) which are passed to your Spark instance

Comment: Where class learning.spark.models.TransactionRecord belongs?  to the same project as your method public void loadTransactions?

Comment: Yes the class exists in the same project. How can I see what package is created and passed to the spark context?

Comment: can you describe more how you deploy the job? which kind of web-service you using, have you implemented it?